# Qual a melhor forma de acompanhar o fluxo do software?

Tags: java, debug, intellij-idea

Tenho um projeto grande, como faço para acompanhar o fluxo (passo por passo)?

Tenho várias classes e não faço ideia quais metódos são chamados, quais classes são etc. Coloquei um breakpoint num ponto que eu sei que passa por ali, no modo debug mas aí ele passa o ponto e continua o fluxo normalmente.

Comment: Qual linguagem e *debugger* está usando?

Comment: @bigown IntelliJ e Java

Comment: De uma olhada e diga se pode te ajudar: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/debugging.html

Comment: Qual é o objetivo? Seria compreender como o sistema funciona (tipo uma engenharia reversa)? Pergunto isso porque a resposta do colega que sugeriu a JUnity faz sentido se a sua necessidade é, por exemplo, descobrir onde há um problema (algo mais próximo à depuração que você mesma cita, mas que não explica exatamente porque não serve).

Comment: Supondo que eu esteja certo em inferir que você deseja entender como o sistema está estruturado, talvez seja mais fácil você usar alguma ferramenta de modelagem que seja capaz de importar do código certos diagramas, como o diagrama de classes, e então estudar a estrutura do sistema em termos de componentes e classes. Sem querer fazer (e já fazendo) propaganda de uma ferramenta paga, a única que eu lembro que faz muito bem isso é o [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/).

Comment: O código funciona perfeitamente e vou somente refatorar, o problema é que o sistema é enorme e está de dificil compreensão. Vou buscar tentar transformar p diagrama de classes, mais legivel

Comment: Uma solução ao invés de ferramentas pagas:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/uml_class_diagram.html

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a framework **[JUnit](http://junit.org/)**. Que tem como finalidade facilitar a criação de código para a automação de testes com apresentação dos resultados. Com ele, pode ser verificado se cada método de uma classe funciona da forma esperada, exibindo possíveis erros ou falhas podendo ser utilizado tanto para a execução de baterias de testes como para extensão.

Comment: Não preciso de testes, eu quero acompanhar o fluxo do programa em tempo de execução: Poder retornar a próxima e a linha anterior de código, igual o modo debug

Comment: Nesse caso, pode olhar o manual da própria IDE, como sugerido acima.

Comment: Bom, não tem nada a ver com a pergunta.